# Stack Overflow Questions Notifier - LinuxMint Cinnamon Applet that notifies you when new questions, with certain tag(s), are posted on Stackoverflow

Tags: app, linux

## Description

A Linux Mint Cinnamon Applet that checks Stack Overflow site and shows a notification popup when new questions (with one or several tags) are posted

## Screenshot

[(Click for a larger view)

[image: Screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDVSr.png)

## Cinnamon spices site

[Stack Overflow Questions Notifier 1.0](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/224)

## Installation

On your Cinnamon based Linux Mint distro:

1. Right click on your panel, click *Add applets to the panel*
2. Click on *Get more online* tab
3. Find *Stackoverflow Questions Notifier*, right click and *Mark for installation*
4. Once installed add it to the panel
5. Right click on the applet icon, click *Configure*, set the tags you're interested in and the frequency time, defaults values are: `c, java, bash, javascript` for tags and `5` minutes for time

If your prefer, you can run the following commands:

```
wget http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/uploads/applets/V9G9-E9F4-3SKP.zip -O tmp.zip
unzip tmp.zip -d ~/.local/share/cinnamon/applets/
    
# Execute this to bring the "Add applet" dialog box
cinnamon-settings applets add 

# Execute this to set the applet configuration
cinnamon-settings applets stackoverflow-questions-notifier@higuaro
```

### Platforms

This applet has been tested on Linux Mint Rebecca 17.1 with Cinnamon 2.4.6. Prior versions of Cinnamon hasn't been tested yet, so any feedback would be highly appreciated.

### License

[The MIT License (MIT)](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

### Code

JavaScript with support of some of the EcmaScript 6 features like `let` and `conts`, and wrappers around some of the libraries that Gnome 3 is built upon.

Repo: `git clone https://github.com/higuaro/stackoverflow-questions-notifier.git`

[GitHub of the project](https://github.com/higuaro/stackoverflow-questions-notifier)